# parsing tcl script to excel without tcom

Tags: excel, tcl

So i have this tcl code which opens an excel macro

```
    >set filename {C:\\test.xlsm}

    >set shortname [file attributes $filename -shortname]

    >exec cmd.exe /k start $shortname &`
```

But i want to put a previously defined variable from my tcl script into the first cell in the excel file. How do i do this without a tcom package? Or is this the only way? My compiler doesn't recognize package require tcom so I'd like to use another method

Comment: If by "doesn't recognize" you mean that it can't find the package, you should be able to install it using `teacup install tcom`  .

Comment: You need tcom to do that.

Comment: where? in my code or in command prompt? another issue I have is that i dont know where my tcl library is and "info library" doesn't work either

Comment: or is it possible to pass in an argument from the command prompt into the visual basic editor

Comment: You call `teacup` from a command prompt or interactive shell (tclsh, wish, tkcon).